# How to change the value here?

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid

I'm creating a rock, paper, scissors game. I can change the player choice at `player.currentChoice = choices[2];`

However I also linked the choice to an HTML button, once clicked it should change the `player.currentChoice = choices[0];` to show 0 as this is the choice for rock.

How do I update the main `player.currentChoice = choices[2];` to `player.currentChoice = choices[0];`? My function doesn't work at all I know this isn't the proper way. I basically need the `player.currentchoice` outside the function to update, to trigger the rest of my game.

```
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
}

const choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

player.currentChoice = choices[2];

document.getElementById('rock').addEventListener('click', updateRock);

function updateRock(){
    player.currentChoice = choices[0];
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Do you need a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler maybe (to execute your code after the DOM is loaded)

Comment: Checkout this, similar to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804922/how-do-i-disable-the-click-event-once-a-certain-condition-is-met/63805094#63805094

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="rock">Rock</button> 
<button id="paper">Paper</button> 
<button id="scissors">Scissors</button>     
    
    const player = {
      currentChoice: null
    }
    const computer = {
      currentChoice: null
    }
    const choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    
    player.currentChoice = choices[2];
    var rockBtn = document.getElementById('rock');
    var paprBtn = document.getElementById('paper');
    var scirBtn = document.getElementById('scissors');
    
    if(rockBtn || paprBtn || scirBtn) {
        rockBtn.addEventListener('click', updateVar);
        paprBtn.addEventListener('click', updateVar);
        scirBtn.addEventListener('click', updateVar);
    }
    function updateVar(event){
        if(event.target.id == 'rock'){
            player.currentChoice = choices[0];
        } else if (event.target.id == 'paper'){
            player.currentChoice = choices[1];
        } else if (event.target.id == 'scissors'){
            player.currentChoice = choices[2];
        }
        console.log(player.currentChoice);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this:

```
const player = { currentChoice: null };
const computer = { currentChoice: null };
const choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
player.currentChoice = choices[2];
window.onload = function() {
const rockButton = document.getElementById('rock');
rockButton.addEventListener('click', updateRock);
};
function updateRock(){
player.currentChoice = choices[0];
}
```

It might be because the Html button is not loading when this script is fired.

Comment: I have my button like this: <button id="rock">Rock</button>

Comment: Why use the window `load` event instead of the `DOMContentLoaded` event?